# DataTables columnas (subcolumnas)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

solicito de su apoyo realmente apenas estoy interactuando con DataTables y no cuento con la experiencia aun , tengo una tabla con jQuery pero me gustaria que mi tabla las columnas tengan subcolumnas al momento de cargarle datos como en el siguiente ejemplo AÑO,PRODUCTO Y CANTIDAD

[[image: 1]

NOTA: Actualmente solo inserte datos directamente en el HTML y la columna mes solo reciba un dato.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#data").DataTable({
      'pageLength': 6,
      "language": {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json",
         },
      responsive:true,
      scrollY:250, 
      
      
    });
  });



   <!-- DataTable -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row d-flex">
            <div class="col-lg-12 p-3">
                <table id="data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%">
                    <thead style="background-color:#FF6400">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-white">MES</th>
                            <th class="text-white">AÑO</th>
                            <th class="text-white">PRODUCTO</th>
                            <th class="text-white">CANTIDAD</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="text-center">
                        <tr >
                            <td>Enero</td>
                            <td>2016<br>2017</td>
                            <td>Sabritas<br> Cocacola </td>
                            <td>13<br> 15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td>Febrero</td>
                            <td>2016<br>2017</td>
                            <td>Donas<br>Boing </td>
                            <td>13<br> 15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td>Marzo</td>
                            <td>2016<br>2017</td>
                            <td>Fanta<br> Victoria </td>
                            <td>13<br> 15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td>Mayo</td>
                            <td>2016<br>2017</td>
                            <td>Doritos<br> Gomitas </td>
                            <td>13<br> 15</td>
                        </tr>



                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```